# EF6 - get all related children

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-6

So, we've created a interview. It is built something like this:

```
class interview
{
         public virtual ICollection<WebQuestionPage> WebQuestionPage { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in the WebQuestionPage class we have

```
   public virtual ICollection<WebQuestionSection> WebQuestionSection { get; set; }
```

sections!

And each section might contain another, nested, section and/or questions

```
        public virtual ICollection<WebQuestionSection> WebQuestionSection1 { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<WebQuestion> WebQuestion { get; set; }
```

The WebQuestion class is the same, it might contain another, nested, question and/or options for the question.

Now, I want to load this entire interview with as low of a loading time as possible.

I did this:

```
 interview = _dbWeb.WebInterview.Include("WebQuestionPage")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestionType")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionOption")
            .Include("WebQuestionPage.WebQuestionSection.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestionSection1.WebQuestion.WebQuestion1.WebQuestionType")
            
            ... and so on
```

which, really, isn't that beautiful, easily read, or fast because it will join even if there is no nested children.

This is written is ASP.NET MVC using EF6.

Comment: Pure SQL and Recursive CTE. It is fastest way to retrieve  hierarchy.

Comment: Consider a NoSQL solution (if you can).